# What kind of Queues are lists and dictionaries?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm just wondering what kind of queues are lists and dictionaries in C#. Whether they're FIFOs or LIFOs.

Comment: This is probably a trick homework question, to see if you're paying attention.

Comment: lol.. No.. I need to know for my program whether or not I should implement a FiFO queue or save me some headache and use in-built logic :P

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Lists and dictionaries are containers that don't support a queue model, that is, they're neither LIFO nor FIFO.  Put another way, you're not comparing apples with apples.

Answer (score 11):

In C#, if you want a LIFO (stack) use [System.Collections.Generic.Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx), and if you want a FIFO (queue) use [System.Collections.Generic.Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

Dictionaries and lists aren't queues, and also FIFO and LIFO doesn't apply to C# lists and dictionaries. You can add/remove items anywhere in a list. You can also add/remove any entry in a dictionary. Not only at the beginning or at the end. Also, a dictionary isn't ordered so there is not even a concept of a beginning and an end.

Comment: To extend this further, the documentation for Dictionary<TKey, TValue> actually states that the items are unordered and can be returned in any order when enumerating.